# Найти пароль 7zip

Tags: zip, пароль

Пароль 7zip

Доброго времени суток!
Требуется помощь с получением пароля на 7zip архив. Пароль забыл, количество символов не помню, но не больше 8, какие знаки там были, тоже не помню. Поможет кто распаковать?
Очень был бы рад паролю, но если сбросите инструкцию - буду рад не меньше.
Прикрепляю ссылку на Яндекс Диск с архивами, берите любой

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/165j_YGkCH1LYsaAt8ONsNbbpfZCS2nER?usp=sharing

Comment: (https://blog.elcomsoft.ru/2021/08/vosstanovlenie-parolej-k-arhivam-formaty-zip-rar5-i-7zip/) на топовой видеокарте 30000 паролей в секунду - 8 символов (большие и маленькие буквы и цифры) будут подбираться свыше 200 лет :) - посмотрите ссылку, там название программ для подбора паролей

Comment: Я захочу взломать пароль к чужому архиву, но поплачусь, что забыл пароль - тоже поможете? Не утверждаю, что автор взломщик, но как отличить  одно от другого? **На открытых площадках такие вопросы не обсуждаются**